# Promise в цикле

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, async-await, promise

Здравствуйте. Есть объект workspace и входной JSON. Необходимо отформатировать и/или получить данные и записать их в этот workspace. Использую цикл для перебора элементов JSON, при этом значения уже существующие, такие как текст, например, попадают в workspace, а данные, которые нужно ждать (получить курс валют например), приходят после выполнения цикла. Для последних использую промисы, но все равно, они приходят после. Помогите разобраться. Ниже код:

```js
var checkJson = function(json) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var workspace = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      var id = json[i].id.match(/\D+/)[0];
      switch (id) {
        case 'background':
          workspace['background'] = {};
          workspace['background'] = createBackground(json[i], workspace['background']);
          break;
        case 'text':
          if (countert == 0) {
            workspace['text'] = {}
          }
          workspace['text'] = createText(json[i], workspace['text']);
          countert++;
          break;
        case 'time':
          if (countertime == 0) {
            workspace['time'] = {}
          }
          createTime(json[i], workspace['time'])
            .then(res => {
              workspace['time'] = res;
              countertime++;
            });
          break;
        case 'currencycourse':
          if (counterCourse == 0) {
            workspace['currencycourse'] = {}
          }
          createCurrensyCourse(json[i], workspace['currencycourse'])
            .then(res => {
              workspace['currencycourse'] = res;
              counterCourse++;
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            });
          break;
          // default:
          //     console.log(itm_id);
          //     break;
      }
    }
    Promise.all([workspace])
      .then(values => {
        // console.log("values", values);
        resolve(values);
      });
  });
};
```

Проблема именно с курсом валют, последний resolve выкидывает заполненный workspace, только currencycourse = {}

Comment: проблема должна уйти сама, если переписать на async/await, так как код будет ожидать резолв промисов в синхронном стиле

Comment: кстати   каунтеры типа  counterCourse не нужны, так как можно писать `workspace['currencycourse'] = workspace['currencycourse'] || {}` или, ещё лучше, проинициализировать объект заранее

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, в самом начале описать, что каждый из workspace[example] = workspace[example] || {}?

Comment: это стандартный js трюк - если мы не уверены, существует ли объект, то можно присвоить ему = себя || {}

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko, Спасибо, полезно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется так:

```
async function checkJson(json): Promise<any> {

    const workspace = {
      background: {},
      text: {},
      time: {},
      currencyCourse: {}
    };

    for (const jsonNode of json.length) {

      const id = jsonNode.id.match(/\D+/)[0];

      switch (id) {
        case 'background':
          workspace.background = createBackground(json[i], workspace.background);
          break;

        case 'text':
          workspace.text = createText(json[i], workspace.text);
          break;

        case 'time':
          workspace.time = await createTime(json[i], workspace['time']);
          break;

        case 'currencycourse':
          workspace.currencyCourse = await createCurrensyCourse(json[i], workspace.currencyCourse)
          break;

        default:
          console.log('default');
      }
    }

    return workspace;
};
```

Comment: но надо  добавить try-catch блок или на асинхронные операции или общий

Comment: Благодарю! Работает